# How to connect quick link for 6/7/8 gears Shimano chain?

Tags: shimano, chain, master-link

I recently ordered a new chain and I am having trouble connecting the quick link, which I also ordered (first time doing it). It seems the pin of the quick link won't stick out far enough to be able to catch and hold the opposite end of the quick link as demonstrated in the pictures below:
[image]

[image]

The size/specifications of the chain and link should match. Could anybody give me a pointer to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You say that the specs of the chain and quicklink should match; can you provide them so we have a better idea what you're working with?

Comment: Looks like these parts don't match. Are you trying to use a 8sp link on a wide 6sp chain or something like that?

Comment: This is the chain:
https://www.cykelpartner.dk/kaeder-mm/cykelkaede-shimano-nexus-gearsystem----rustbeskyttet--ecnnx10c114i?gad_source=1

Got the quick links from AliExpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001267550243.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.3.55d02b05jEdjFj&algo_pvid=1b9b4d31-6388-47d2-8f9a-553affee67de&utparam-url=scene%3Asearch%7Cquery_from%3A

I was sure I had the specifications matched up.. The gears are internal Shimano Nexus

Comment: Where it went wrong I don't know. But the terrain is what matters, not the map. That pin on the quicklink seems to be too short for your chain unless you are not pushing it through properly in the pic. Hard to find the dimensions of these things, but you can measure them yourself with a caliper if you want to know.

Comment: @WornChain Got it, thanks for help!

Comment: I find these a lot harder to fit than the QLs on newer 11/12-speed groupsets. It helps a lot to fixate the chain with a piece of wire (or the hooks on many chain gauge tools) to free your hands up a bit to push the plates together (I know, there probably isn't enough slack in the system with a Nexus hub, but generally...)